# angular2 rxjs shared subscribe not firing

Tags: angular, rxjs

Angular2 2.0.0-beta.15, Rxjs 5.0.0-beta.2

I have two simple rxjs observables, one shared, one not (.share() called on it)

I have an angular2 component which subscribes to both observables and also displays the values in its template, which also subscribes to the observables with async pipe.

I click a button to set .next() on both observables with some garbage.

The template updates and shows the latest value of each.
The subscription function in the component does NOT fire for the non-shared observable. Why?

plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/IIWvnTT1zLit1eUNknkk?p=preview

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>obs1 value: {{ observable1 | async }}</div>
            <div>obs2 value: {{ observable2 | async }}</div>
            <button (click)="randomizeIt()">randomize it</button>

            <br>
            <h3>Question 1</h3>
            Why is obs1's initial value (from startWith) not displayed?

            <h3>Question 2</h3>
            Why does our subscription to obs2 never fire on new values?<br>
            check console.log to see what i mean.
        </div>`,
})
export class App {

    public observable1:Observable<string>;
    public observer1:any;
    public observable2:Observable<string>;
    public observer2:any;

    constructor() {
        this.observable1 = Observable.create(observer => {
            this.observer1 = observer;
        }).startWith("initial obs 1 value").share();

        this.observable1.subscribe((val) => {
            console.log('YOU WILL SEE THIS:', val);
        })

        this.observable2 = Observable.create(observer => {
            this.observer2 = observer;
        }).startWith("initial obs 2 value"); // no share!

        this.observable2.subscribe((val) => {
            console.log('WHY DOES THIS NEVER FIRE ON NEW VALUES?:', val);
        })

    }

    public randomizeIt() {
        let r = Math.random();
        console.log('set both obs to: ', r);
        this.observer1.next(r);
        this.observer2.next(r);
    }   

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q1. **Why is obs1's initial value (from startWith) not displayed?**

From the [share()](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) docs:

> Returns an observable sequence that shares a single subscription to the underlying sequence.

Which means, in your case, `{{ observable1 | async }}` and `this.observable1.subscribe(....)` are sharing the same subscription and when you subscribed to `observable1` in the constructor, you already started the sequence. When the view initialized, the subscription to `observable1` was already started and the first value emitted. So `async` will call `subscribe()`, but will not get the first emit of the sequence.

So, if you move the subscription to inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, the initial value will go to `async` subscription.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.observable1.subscribe((val) => {
        console.log('YOU WILL SEE THIS CHANGE:', val);
    })
}
```

---

Q2. **Why does our subscription to obs2 never fire on new values?**

Every time you subscribe to a **cold** Observable, you actually create a new Observable instance. When you create a new instance, you create a new observer instance also. So, your subscription on the constructor is to observable `instance1` and observer `instance1` and the subscription by `async` is to observable `instance2` and observer `instance2`. So, when you call `randomizeIt()`, you call `observer2` the `instance2` which is bound to observable `instance2` subscribed to by `async`.

To make your observable "hot":

```
let obs = Observable.create(observer => {
    this.observer2 = observer;
}).startWith("initial obs 2 value");
this.observable2 = obs.publish();
    
this.observable2.subscribe((val) => {
    console.log('WHY DOES THIS NEVER FIRE?:', val);
})
this.observable2.connect();
```

**Update**
let's say you have an observable that emits a random value:

```
this.observable3 = Observable.create(observer => {
    observer.next(Math.random());
});
```

Now, every time you subscribe to `this.observable3` you will get a new random value. Not the same value for every subscriber. Because there is a new instance for each subscriber.

From the docs:

> It helps to think of cold and hot Observables as movies or performances that one can watch ("subscribe").
>
> > **Cold Observables**: movies.
> > **Hot Observables**: live performances.
> > **Hot Observables replayed**: live performances recorded on video.
>
> Whenever you watch a movie, your run of the movie is independent of anyone else's run, even though all movie watchers see the same effects. On the other hand, a live performance is shared to multiple viewers. If you arrive late to a live performance, you will simply miss some of it. However, if it was recorded on video (in RxJS this would happen with a BehaviorSubject or a ReplaySubject), you can watch a "movie" of the live performance. A .publish().refCount() live performance is one where the artists quit playing when no one is watching, and start playing again when there is at least one person in the audience.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the Q1 answer. But I don't yet understand Q2. I notice if i remove {{ observable2 | async }}, my observer2 subscription will fire upon randomizeIt. need more coffee

Comment: @user2073082 exactly, because when you remove `{{ observable2 | async }}` there will only be one instance of `observable2`. In other words, you only called `this.observable2.subscribe()` once. Therefore, you only have one instance of that Observable.

Comment: @user2073082  check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/u1ddd4ZQCEzjTLElTs1Q?p=preview) . `observable2` will emit a random value. Because there are two instances of that Observable. The value on `{{ observable2 | async }}` is different than the one on the log.

Comment: AAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH.....I GET IT NOW!
every time i called subscribe on observable2 it was creating a new observable and setting this.observer2 to the observer of that new observable!!!!  boy, the terminology is confusing. it seems like a different term should be used for "observable2" and the observable created from observable2.subscribe...instead of calling both observables. confusing!

Comment: @user2073082 glad to hear that. The AAAAHHH moment is always the best :).  And, you are right. `observable2` is more like an observable creator. hence the `Observable.create(...)`

Comment: @Abdulrahman "So, when you call randomizeIt(), you call observer2 the instance2 which is bound to observable instance2 subscribed to by async".  Why does this happen? Why does it not go to observer1-> what makes it choose observer2?

Comment: @ZammyPage observer1 was called. But the OP was asking about observer2 which doesn't get called. My answer explains the reason why that happens.